# How to correctly map a foreign key using JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, named-query

I have the following mapping for joining tables 'Company and 'Employee'

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
@SecondaryTable(name = "employee",  pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id"))

@NamedQuery(name = "findEmp",
            query = "SELECT C FROM Company c WHERE c.employee_id=:eid")
```

I get the following error for the namedQuery

```
could not resolve property: employee_id
```

When I try to add an explicit member 'employee_id' in the Company table, I get a 'repeated mapping exception. What may be the issue?

Comment: What is s in s.employee_id ?

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Edited it

Comment: so where is field "employee_id" in class Company???? Note I said field there not column. Also note that people here can't see your classes, so you expect guesswork

Comment: Also, SecondaryTable is used when a given entity corresponds to two rows of two tables. Clearly, company and employee are not a good fit for it: you should use a OneToMany association instead: a company typically has more than one employee.